# Where to specify line height for sIFR

Tags: sifr

I have not had any luck changing the line height for sIFR. I have tried changing the sIFR css and config file as well as my general style sheet. Is there a special trick?

### GENERAL CSS

```
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 16px; (has had zero impact, even when I go negative)
    color: #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}
```

### CONFIG FILE

```
sIFR.replace(minionpro, {
  selector: 'h1', wmode: 'transparent',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color:#000000; text-transform: uppercase; }'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Flash uses `leading` instead of `line-height`, so simply just use:

```
sIFR.replace(minionpro, {
  selector: 'h1', wmode: 'transparent',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color:#000000; text-transform: uppercase; leading: 1.5; }'
});
```

The `leading` value must just be a number on its own with no measurement value such as px, em, %, etc.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought it wasn't working, but I realized that the units for leading are totally different from em. I tried a larger value "leading: -10;" and it worked fine. I'm using sIFR 3 r436.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that because your font-size > line-height (24px > 16px) sIFR is going to ignore the line-height property and use the font-size to create your flash.

If you're trying to get two lines of overlapping text (24px text on a 16px line will result in 8px of overlap), you're probably stretching the capabilities of sIFR.

**EDIT**

It looks like sIFR has some strange methods for calculating font size based on different factors...check out the link for the details (without knowing your version of sIFR, I can't comment on your situation).

[Novemberborn: Font Sizing with sIFR](http://novemberborn.net/sifr3/font-sizing)

Comment: I just did that as a test to see if it would do anything. I had it at 24px for a flush appearance but no matter what I put in, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Line height inside the Flash movie is controlled using the (custom) `leading` CSS property for the `.sIFR-root` class. Flash doesn't have the concept of `line-height` as you might be familiar with from CSS.